# Swift Realm add days to date in filter

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I would like to filter some Realm results in Swift based on a date and a number of days.  I have a Realm Object  that has the following properties:

```
class Route: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Codable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: Int?
    @Persisted var status: String?
    @Persisted var bucket_name: String?
    @Persisted var frequency_days: Int?
    @Persisted var last_record_date: Date?
}
```

And what I would like to do is add the number of days in `frequency_days` to the `last_record_date` while I am filtering the results.

In my View I would like to do something like this (I know you can't add an Int to a Date, but this is just to illustrate my goal):

```
self.filteredRoutes = self.routes.where {
    ($0.last_record_date + $0.frequency_days < Date())
}
```

I also couldn't find anything in the [filter section of the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/examples/filter-data/)

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but if anyone has some ideas to get this to work or a work around, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I think we can make this work but need a bit more info. Suppose the `last_record_date` is 2022-04-01 and frequency_days is 10 (days). So if you add the number of days onto `last_record_date`, the resultant date is 2022-04-10 (including the 1st). So what exactly do you want from your query - do you want it to return resultant dates that are less than today e.g. `Date()`? If so, why not just store that date? You know the `last_record_date` and the `frequency_days` so why not add them together and store that? If that's not what you want, can you clarify what you are after?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want.  I ended up modifying my API to do the calculation for me, so I am now doing just as you suggested.  Realm is now storing the calculated date which is making things much easier.  Thank you for the insight

Comment: Excellent. Glad to help. I added an answer per the above and also a suggestion if you need to store all three properties with a class based calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just storing the actual date you want to query against.

You know the last_record_date and the frequency_days so why not add them together and store that as a date.

For example;

Suppose the last_record_date is 2022-04-01 and frequency_days is 10 (days).

If you add the number of days onto last_record_date, the resultant date is 2022-04-10 (including the 1st).

So store that at a target_date property: 2022-04-10

Any time the either the frequency date or last_record_date changes you can simply calculate a new target date and store that.

I would suggest adding a function to you Realm class to do that for you, and if you need to store the frequency_days and last_record_date you can do that as well.

```
class Route: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable, Codable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: Int?
    @Persisted var frequency_days: Int?
    @Persisted var last_record_date: Date?

    @Persisted var target_date: Date?

    func changeFrequencyDays(newDayCount: Int) {
        self.frequency_days = newDayCount

        //do some math to add newDayCount to the last_record_date
        self.target_date = //new calculated date
    }

    func changeLastRecordDate(lastRecordDate: Date) {
        self.last_record_date = lastRecordDate

        //do some math to add frequency_days to the new lastRecordDate
        self.target_date = //new calculated date
    }
}
```

With the above, any time a frequency_days need to be updated or the last_record_date changes, call the appropriate function and that property will be updated along with updating the target_date property.